# What did I miss thing in the XML?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml, android-layout-weight

When I developed my app 1 years ago, the position was right, but now, something is wrong (cropped).

I don't know what I missed. I think I used the right things 'weight' attribute in the XML.

This is the code and the result in the phone. (Mine is Galaxy S6 Edge, Nougat)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_qna_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:text="Content"
    android:textColor="#000" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_qna_regdtm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="REG_DTM"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_qna_update"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_qna_update"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_qna_answer"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_qna_answer"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_qna_delete"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_qna_delete"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

And the original picture is it!

[image]

Comment: What's the problem with the result?

Comment: yea whats wrong , spacing?

Comment: @TentenPonce I edit my write. bottom is cut in the app.

Comment: @Remario I edit the write. no spacing is right due to margin. but the image is cut ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_qna_update"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_qna_update"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```

It seems that you're limiting the height of the button that's why the image is getting cut. Try to use `wrap_content`.

Comment: Omg... Thanks..!! If i want to use the image, is the wrap_content is flexible ?? Is it right..??

Comment: Yes, `wrap_content` adjusts the width/height of the view just to enclose its content.

Comment: Thanks!! you save my time. and I have a work...lol I check all of my xml. Thanks again!